# is it possible to avoid open files?

Tags: files, rhel, process, ps, lsof

when we run lsof to capture deleted files ,

we see the following: ( example )

```
lsof +L1
java      193699  yarn 1760r   REG   8,16      719     0  93696130 /grid/sdb/hadoop/hdfs/data/current/PLP-428352611-43.21.3.46-1502127526112/current/path/nbt/dir37/blk_1186014689_112276769.meta (deleted)
```

what is the reason that PID still running in spite files already deleted

```
lsof +L1 | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
193699
```

is it possible to avoid this scenario?

Comment: Don't delete them?

Comment: The application still holds a open handle to those files. The application would need to release the handle (close the file) to make the file really disappear.

Comment: @Hermann Yeah, the general answer is that one. If the OP is satisfied with the answer, write it down.... any other answer wont be much better with the level of detail of the question.

Comment: Most apps have open files (title). You've pointed out an app with open , deleted files. You then ask why the app is running like that and how to avoid the scenario. What do you want to see happen? The app stop when an open file is deleted?

Comment: If it's you who wrote that java app, take care to close any file handles when you no longer need them -- notice that unlike memory objects, file handles are **not** automatically garbage collected (that could only work in a language which is using reference counting, like `perl`; if you don't close a stream in `java`, any fd it's using will leak when the object it's part of is destroyed)

Comment: can we just kill the PID , since PID not have any add value ,

Comment: I mean in case the files any way are not exist , then we must to kill the PID , because the PID take resource as load average CPU

Comment: Note the 4 row is telling r (file descriptor in read access mode) and until is not closed the file will be there. If you need to erase it you can use gdb.

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: You will need to run gdb against the $PID (193699) and then close (every 4th row number). Note that you should not trust me before reading the documentation because I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming style issue, not a U&L issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long to put in a comment, so adding as an answer:

That's a Java application keeping those files open, so *yes, this scenario can be avoided* by using a proper programming style and using the `ObjectOutputStream` object:

```
//create a Serializable List
List lNucleotide = Arrays.asList(
  "adenine", "cytosine", "guanine", "thymine", "sylicine"
);

//serialize the List
//note the use of abstract base class references

try{
  //use buffering
  OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("lNucleotide.ser");
  OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
  ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
  try{
output.writeObject(lNucleotide);
  }
  finally{
output.close();
  }
}  
catch(IOException ex){
  logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot create Silicon life form.", ex);
}
```

By closing the file at an application level you *will avoid this problem*. So this is not a result of Unix or Linux doing anything wrong but inherent to your application.

Comment: (And the answer was also posted to make all Computational Biologists here smile...)

Comment: Just want to point out a separate possibility -- that the files were removed outside of the java program.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Oh, you mean the OP wants to know how to *avoid having the files deleted?* (I.e. Exclusive lock?)  Ping me in chat.

Comment: it's [entirely unclear to me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494287/is-it-possible-to-avoid-open-files/494296?noredirect=1#comment908241_494287) what the OP wants, as I've commented and voted.

Comment: @JeffSchaller [new Q posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494312/90054) and [edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/494312/revisions) after chat what he's trying to accomplish...

Comment: I would swear Java garbage collector does not close open files....+1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Apparently: *Garbage collection will only free the resources within the JVM. The resources assigned to the VM by the operating system will still be reserved.* (Edited)

Comment: “a proper programming style” — better still, use try-with-resources!